# YUI create div in every input[type=text]

Tags: javascript, css, yui

Hi ~ pardon my ignorance,
I'm new to YUI3.
I would like to create a clear button in every input textbox.
So my attempt is create a div and append to every input text.
However my attempt fail.

Kindly need your guidance here on the code my tried below..

Thanks in advance!

```
YUI().use("node", function(Y) {
     Y.all('input[type=text]').each(function(node) {

         var outerDiv = Y.Node.create('<div class="clrInput">X</div>');
          outerDiv.setStyles({
                position:  absolute,
                left: node.get('offsetLeft')+this.get('width')-10,
                top: node.get('offsetTop'),
                width:node.get('width'),
                height:node.get('height')
        })

         node.appendTo(outerDiv);
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for why you are not seeing anything is that `outerDiv` never becomes a part of the DOM. It's created, and the `input` node is `append`ed to it, but `outerDiv` itself is never added to the DOM.

```
node.appendTo(outerDiv);
Y.one('body').append(outerDiv);
```

Should solve that. Check out [your script with that line added](http://jsfiddle.net/DdmKQ/).

Comment: Thanks a million! :D i guess i just need to work at the css now..:)